# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'segment'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, mean-shift

Facing error in image segmentation using meanshift algorithm in following line:

```
import cv2
(segmented_image, labels_image, number_regions) = cv2.meanShift.segment(im, spatial_radius=6, range_radius=4.5, min_density=50)
```

complete traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_processing.py", line 16, in <module>
    (segmented_image, labels_image, number_regions) = cv2.meanShift.segment(im,
spatial_radius=6,
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'segment'
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us which part of the error message you don't understand.

Comment: I want to use meanshift algorithm and I am unable to find this 'segment ' function....can u tell me which package contain this function in python?

Answer (score -1):

This error is telling you `cv2.meanShift` does not refer to a property, but rather a function/method.  You're calling it as if it's a property.  Look at the API for `cv2` and make sure you are calling `meanShift` as a function with the proper arguments.